# jQuery populated Gridview losing data on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview that I populate clientside using javascript (jQuery), I need to get the data to the server on postback.  Obviously any data processed client side will be lost on a normal postback, looking for best method to persist client side data on postback.

My jQuery code for a monthly payment plan(works perfectly):

```
totalmonths = moment(paymentbydate).diff(today, 'month');
var totalamount = ((amountdue / totalmonths) + ((amountdue / totalmonths) * processingfee));

var weeklyamount = toFixed(amountdue / totalmonths, 2);
var paymentprocessingfee = toFixed((amountdue / totalmonths) * processingfee, 2);
var lastpayment = 0;
totalamount = toFixed(parseFloat(weeklyamount) + parseFloat(paymentprocessingfee), 2); //(amountdue/totalweeks) + ((amountdue / totalweeks) * processingfee);

// Add first payment to grid
$("#<%=GridView_PaymentSchedule.ClientID%>").append("<tr><td>" + todaydate + "</td><td>" + weeklyamount + "</td><td>" + paymentprocessingfee + "</td><td>" + totalamount + "</td></tr>");
// Add second payment, startdate, to grid
var nextdate = moment(datevalue, 'MM/DD/YYYY').add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
$("#<%=GridView_PaymentSchedule.ClientID%>").append("<tr><td>" + datevalue + "</td><td>" + weeklyamount + "</td><td>" + paymentprocessingfee + "</td><td>" + totalamount + "</td></tr>");

var totalpaymentsmade = parseFloat(totalamount) * 2;
// Total up payment so you can calculate overage/underpayment if any
// add all subsequet payments until paid in full
for (i = 0; i < (totalmonths - 2) ; i++) {
    totalpaymentsmade = totalpaymentsmade + parseFloat(totalamount); // Total up the next payment
    var nextpayment  = toFixed(totalpaymentsmade - amountduewithfee, 2);
    if (nextpayment == 0) {
        $("#<%=GridView_PaymentSchedule.ClientID%>").append("<tr><td>" + nextdate + "</td><td>Final Payment: " + weeklyamount + "</td><td>" + paymentprocessingfee + "</td><td>" + totalamount + "</td></tr>");
        break;
    } else {
        $("#<%=GridView_PaymentSchedule.ClientID%>").append("<tr><td>" + nextdate + "</td><td>" + weeklyamount + "</td><td>" + paymentprocessingfee + "</td><td>" + totalamount + "</td></tr>");
    }
    nextdate = moment(nextdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    numpayments += 1;
    // check if next payment is overpayment or underpayment but under payment amount
    lastpayment = toFixed(amountduewithfee - totalpaymentsmade, 2);
    if (totalpaymentsmade > amountduewithfee) {
        $("#<%=GridView_PaymentSchedule.ClientID%>").append("<tr><td>" + nextdate + "</td><td>Final Payment</td><td>0</td><td>" + lastpayment + "</td></tr>");
        break;
    } else if ((amountduewithfee - totalpaymentsmade) < amountduewithfee && (amountduewithfee - totalpaymentsmade) < totalamount) {
        $("#<%=GridView_PaymentSchedule.ClientID%>").append("<tr><td>" + nextdate + "</td><td>Final Payment</td><td>0</td><td>" + lastpayment + "</td></tr>");
        break;
    } else if (totalpaymentsmade == amountduewithfee) {
        $("#<%=GridView_PaymentSchedule.ClientID%>").append("<tr><td>" + nextdate + "</td><td>Final Payment</td><td>0</td><td>" + lastpayment + "</td></tr>");
        break;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After some research, seems like the best way to handle this situation is to use ajax to post the data to the server via a webmethod which I do but now when I call the method with an array of arrays of string, it executes with no errors but no data is received on the server side, I get an empty list.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PaymentPlan.aspx/SaveGridViewData",
    data: '{pPayments: ' + JSON.stringify({ payments: payments }) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
    alert("Data sucessfully transmited.");
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Data not transmited: error = " + response.responseText);
    }
});
```

payments is an array of arrays, [date,amount,fee,total], all strings to make things simple.

The code behind:
I kept it simple, I put a breakpoint on the `x += 1` to examine the parameter.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub SaveGridViewData(ByVal pPayments As List(Of String()))
    Dim x As Integer
    x += 1
End Sub
```

the result is pPayments is an empty list, I tried `pPayments as List(of string)`, same result.  I also tried creating a class of payments with the four properties and a parameterless constructor and a constructor with parameters, I get `no parameterless constructor defined for this object`.  Clearly I do not understand the issue.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The server does not know you filled the GridVIew with data, so when you do a PostBack every change is lost. If you want to access that data have have to fill the GridView in code behind in the first place, or store the data in a HiddenField, send it to the server and process it there also.

Comment: Thanks, but not knowing the total number of payments that will be necessary makes it difficult to use hidden fields, also, I'm not a fan of hidden fields ... in my opinion it's messy, just my opinion .... looking for more "elegant" options.

Comment: I don't know where the source data is coming from, but you can do ajax web requests in code behind and bind that to the GridView.

Comment: The data is generated clientside, it comes from "no where".  The client selects the payment interval and the number, date of, start date  and payment amount is generated in javascript (jQuery) so there's nothing to bind on page load or in any other event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  I changed how I constructed the JSON object, instead of a array of arrays I construct an array of objects:

**jQuery (ajax) Code:**

```
var thepayment = new Array();

// Pull the data out of the gridview
$('[id*=GridView_PaymentSchedule]').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
    var obj = new Object;
    obj.paymentdate = $(this).find('td').eq(0)[0].innerHTML;
    obj.amount = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0].innerHTML;
    obj.processingfee = $(this).find('td').eq(2)[0].innerHTML;
    obj.totalamount = $(this).find('td').eq(3)[0].innerHTML;

    thepayment.push(obj);
});

// This is the line of code that made the difference
// DTO stands for Data Transfer Object
// Then you JSON stringify it, not all at once.

// This DOES NOT work:
// '{pPayments: ' + JSON.stringify({ payments: thepayment }) + '}'

// This does:
var DTO = { 'pPayments': thepayment };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PaymentPlan.aspx/SaveGridViewData",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO), // '{pPayments: ' + JSON.stringify({ payments: thepayment }) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Data sucessfully transmited.");
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Data not transmited: error = " + response.responseText);
    }
```

});

**payments class:**

```
Public Class payments
    Public Sub New()
        MyClass.New("", "", "", "")
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal pPaymentdate As String, ByVal pAmount As String, ByVal pProcessingfee As String, ByVal pTotalamount As String)
        paymendate = pPaymentdate
        amount = pAmount
        processingfee = pProcessingfee
        totalamount = pTotalamount
    End Sub

    Public Property paymendate As String

    Public Property amount As String

    Public Property processingfee As String

    Public Property totalamount As String

End Class
```

**Web method:**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub SaveGridViewData(ByVal pPayments As List(Of payments))
    ' Do Stuff
End Sub
```